# Flutter Provider - StreamProvider depending on another StreamProvider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-provider

**TLDR**
How to use data from one stream provider to call another?

### Background of the Problem

Hello! I have this Firebase Realtime Database Structure

[image: Users Database Structure.]

Each user's Group IDs are stored here. They can be accessed to then query the following 'Groups' Json tree.

[image: Groups database structure]

Here there is all the data for a group, which multiple users can access. The structure is like this to avoid data redundancy.

### Problem

I am using the Provider package. To get the user data, it works like a charm:

1. I use a Stream Provider
2. I query the database with an onValue function --> Stream.
3. I map the data from that Stream to a class and transform it to that class's structure using fromMap() factory function

```dart
Stream<FrediUser> currentUserDataStream() {
    var userRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users').
    child(currentUserID!);
    return userRef.onValue.map((event) => 
    FrediUser.fromMap(event.snapshot.value));
}
```

That works if I have to access the User map and its nested children. **But as illustrated in the example above, what happens if I have to access the User map first and then the Groups map?** I want to do all of this using stream providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by using the first stream as dependency of the second like below

```
StreamProvider<FrediUser>(
      create: (context) => firstStream(),
      initialData: 'initialData',
      builder: (context, child) {
        return StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => secondStream(
              context.watch<FrediUser>(),
          ),
          initialData: 'initialData',
          child: child,
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: With a bit of tweaking for my use case, this is the correct answer. I was able to get data from the first stream and pass it to the second. For example, I did a first tream of type `User?` where I could access the uid of the current logged in user. Then my second stream (with all the user data) of type `FrediUser` had an updated uid to look up.

Comment: Now I will apply it to the actual case in question, but I am sure it will work the same way